# Type Conversion

Tags: solidity

[image]

I am getting an error on line "_tmp[i] = bytes1((_base % 10) + 48);" and it says explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes1".
The code snippet which i have enclosed converts an integer to it's ASCII string equivalent.

```
function toString(uint _base) 
    internal
    returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory _tmp = new bytes(32);
    uint i;
    for(i = 0;_base > 0;i++) {
        _tmp[i] = bytes1((_base % 10) + 48);
        _base /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory _real = new bytes(i--);
    for(uint j = 0; j < _real.length; j++) {
        _real[j] = _tmp[i--];
    }
    return string(_real);
}
```

Comment: Works for me (except for `Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure`); What is your compiler version?

Comment: I am currently using version 0.5.0

Comment: So maybe convert it to `uint8` first: `bytes1(uint8(_base % 10) + 48)`.